# Can't find Rancher instances in AWS EC2 dashboard

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-ec2

I followed the official AWS quickstart guide from the Rancher website:
https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/quick-start-guide/deployment/amazon-aws-qs/

The tutorial consists in :

- Downloading a Terraform project
- Finding your AWS access
- Changing the `terraform.tfvars` configuration file
- Creating the environment with the command `terraform apply --auto-approve`

When the environnement is created, the Rancher IP is printed in the output and I can access the server.

But I can’t find the machine in my **EC2** instances dashboard.
How can I stop the server? Where is it? It’s supposed to be in AWS

---

### P.S:

I checked that my access are correct with the command

> aws configure

To find the access token, I did:

> aws sts get-session-token

This printed credentials that I copied in the Terraform Configuration file.

## EDIT

Like said by Michael Hampton, the instance is supossed to be in **EKS** cluster, but there is none.

To destroy the environment I have to do:

> terraform destroy --auto-approve

But it seems it stucks in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickstart document you linked to clearly says:

> Two Kubernetes clusters are deployed into your AWS account, one running Rancher Server and the other ready for experimentation deployments.

You can find Kubernetes clusters in your AWS console by going to Elastic Kubernetes Service, and then clicking Clusters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I look at Elastic Kubernetes Service, I can't find it in the cluster section, neither it is in ECS.

Comment: @HamzaInce Did you select the correct region?

Comment: Thank you, the answer was correct.